# oembed - how is the scheme URL published?

Tags: oembed

Providing discovery of your web page in oembed means adding a link such as

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed"
 href="http://flickr.com/services/oembed? 
url=http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fbees%2F2362225867%2F&format=json"
 title="Bacon Lollys oEmbed Profile" />
```

so thats a item URL of
http://flickr.com/photos/bees/2362225867/&format=json

However the URL scheme for this general area in flicker is

http://www.flickr.com/photos/*

and this ends up in the following JSON

https://oembed.com/providers.json

as an entry of

```
{
    "provider_name": "Flickr",
    "provider_url": "https://www.flickr.com/",
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "schemes": [
                "http://*.flickr.com/photos/*",
                "http://flic.kr/p/*",
                "https://*.flickr.com/photos/*",
                "https://flic.kr/p/*"
            ],
            "url": "https://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/",
            "discovery": true
        }
    ]
},
```

Where is this scheme URL obtained from as I don't see it explicitly declared anywhere?

The provider's JSON is supposed to be maintained through discovery via the original s but  they do not contain the scheme URL (with the wildcard *'s).

Answer (score 0):

Using the discovery model there is no URL scheme. Each page on your site (that you want to be embeddable) has to include the link tag and the URL needs to identify that individual page to your endpoint.